# Frequency of display function with glut

Tags: python, opengl, glut

I don't understand what cause exactly the call to the `display` function with glut.

I use PyOpenGL for Python. My program has an `update()` function which is called every 60th of a second, using `glutTimerFunc`.

That's the only function that modify objects at screen, there's absolutely nothing else. So I would expect the `display` function would be called once, after the `update` function has been run.

But that's not the case : the `display` function is called around 10 times between 2 calls to `update()`. It's clearly a waste, and I'm afraid it will slow down the program when it'll be more difficult.

And it makes the fan of my computer noisy...

I tried to put a `glutPostRedisplay()` at the end of my update function, with no difference.

Is there a way to force glut to call `display` only when really needed ?

Comment: In a properly structured program, that is what `glutPostRedisplay (...)` is supposed to be for. If you do something that requires the scene to be re-drawn, call it and GLUT will make a call to your display callback at a later point in time. Rather than immediately calling your display callback, it defers this and multiple `glutPostRedisplay (...)` calls will not necessarily translate into 1-draw-per-call. It is akin to "dirty" framebuffers in older graphics, you know it needs to be re-posted and will get around to it when it makes logical sense; you can only transition to dirty once per-frame.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand why only one (or no) `glutPostRedisplay` translate into multiple `display` calls (your comment explains the contrary).